# 2D array filling from a file

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote this code but somehow it is not working. It is supposed to display these data on the black screen:

1. 187  52  166 297
2. 37   70  212 27
3. 20   179 112 45
4. 244  121 308 19
5. 251  33  212 35

what is wrong with the code?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5][4], i, j, c;
    FILE *inp;
    inp = fopen("votes.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            c = fscanf(inp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
            arr[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
    fclose(inp);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: In `arr[i][j] = c;` you are setting every array element to `1` if the `fscanf` was successful, or `0` if it was not. Please read the man pages for `scanf` family of functions, what the return value means, what its arguments are for.

Comment: @WeatherVane so what should I do, i delete the variable c?

Comment: `if (fscanf(inp,"%d",&c)==1){arr[i][j] = c}` is what you should have.

Comment: I said, read the manual. This is the most basic ability to master, of all.

Answer (score 3):

`fscanf` returns the number of elements filled - not the value it filled into a variable. The value read is written directly in the variable via the pointer-argument (i.e. `&arr[i][j]`).

So instead of

```
c=fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]);
arr[i][j] = c;
```

your code should be:

```
if (1 != fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]))
{
    // something is wrong - fscanf didn't read an int
    ... error handling ...
}
```